# Find two $2\times2$ matrices which have the same eigenvalues, but are not similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, similar-matrices

Find two matrices $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ such that:

- they have the same eigenvalues
- but they are NOT similar

MY ATTEMPT

The characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$ is $p_{\mathbf{A}}(\lambda)=\lambda^{2}-\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A})+\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{A})$ and the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{B}$ is $p_{\mathbf{B}}(\lambda)=\lambda^{2}-\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{B})+\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{B})$.

"The same eigenvalues" $\Longleftrightarrow P_{\mathbf{A}}(\lambda)=P_{\mathbf{B}}(\lambda)\Longleftrightarrow$ $\Longleftrightarrow\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{c}
\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A})=\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{B})\\
\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{A})=\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{B})
\end{array} & \Longleftrightarrow\end{cases}\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}+a_{22}=b_{11}+b_{22}\\
a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}=b_{11}b_{22}-b_{21}b_{12}
\end{array}\end{cases}$

And now?

Comment: You don't need to do fancy math. All you need to do is find an example. Here, I'll give you some numbers to build two matrices out of: $0~0~0~0~0~0~0~1$. Have fun.

Comment: You could pick rotation matrices; they have the same eigenvalues (both are $1$), but they are not similar if they are not the same rotation.

Comment: @LarryB. Rotation matrices do have unit eigenvalues, but they are generally not $1$. The only rotation matrix with eigenvalues of $1$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: @LarryB. For $2\times2$  rotation matrices trace would be $2\cos\theta$ and this is not $1+1$ in general, and so eigen values are not 1.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the matrices
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which clearly have the same eigenvalues, but they are not similar because $B$ is a Jordan block that can't be diagonalized.

Comment: Here's an even simpler example: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\not\sim\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @McFry. True, but I wanted matrices that were invertible.

Comment: @JackyChong: Jordan block would be usually bit advanced for the question under discussion. It is easier to see that identity matrix can be similar to no other matrix as $CIC^{-1}= I$

Comment: @PVanchinathan I agree.